# Set CellTextLabel with JSON and iPhone

Tags: iphone, json, ios4, sdk

I just try to use JSON for the first time. But my data is japanese but it show in cell in UTF format (\u358\u798\u789 Blah Blah Blah)

please take a look to my code.

```
NSError *theError = nil;
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blahblah.com"]];
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];      
NSMutableString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse = [string JSONValue];
self.city = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""]];
```

What can dictionary and JSONValue do ? 
How can I show it in japanese ? Am I wrong in encoding ?

very thank for you help ?

Comment: I try 



self.city = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[string JSONValue] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] ];



and It didn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to parse your json file first. Main JSON parsing libraries for Objective-C are:

- [JSONKit](https://github.com/AquaGeek/JSONKit)
- [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON)
- [yajl](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc)
- [NextiveJson](https://github.com/nextive/NextiveJson)

so first, parse you JSON file, then assign the value to self.city (I don't see any other error).